# A question about the class of all posets

Tags: category-theory, order-theory

I was reading ring and categories of modules and I had a question.

The book is Frank W. Anderson and Kent R. Fuller’s Rings and Categories of Modules.

Let P be the class of all posets, $Hom\left(A,B\right)$ the set of all monotone maps (order preserving and order reversing ones), and $\circ$ the usual composition.

The author says the P is not a category because the composition of two monotone functions need not be monotone.

The following is my attempt.

Let $x\le y$:

If $f$ is an order preserving function and $g$ is an order preserving  function, then $gf$ is also an order preserving function.

If $f$ is an order preserving function and $g$ is an order reversing  function, then $gf$ is  an order reversing function.

If $f$ is an order reversing function and $g$ is an order preserving function, then $gf$ is an order reversing function.

If $f$ is an order reversing function and $g$ is an order reversing function, then $gf$ is an order preserving function.

Did I get it wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: You are correct. This appears to just be a mistake by the author.

Comment: @ Qiaochu Yuan  Thanks！

Answer (score -1):

let $g=1/x,\;0<x\leq \frac{\pi}{2}$.
$g$ is order reversing.

let $f=sin(x),\; 0<x\leq \frac{\pi}{2}$.
$f$ is order preserving.
composition:
$fg=f(g(x))=sin(\frac{1}{x})$ is not order preserving nor reversing as we approach 0.

Comment: This is not a counterexample; you specify that the domain of $f$ should be taken to be $(0, \frac{\pi}{2}]$ and this is necessary for $f$ to be order-preserving, then you apply $f$ to values outside of this domain where it isn't order-preserving.